# How to find the associated conservation law from a given symmetry

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

It is a very well-known fact that any conservation law associated with some given PDE has an associated invariance (by Noether's Theorem). However, it is completely mysterious for me how to compute/derive these conservation laws just by knowing the invariances of the equation. For example, the one-dimensional nonlinear wave equation $$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}+f(u)=0, \qquad (t,x)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},
$$
is invariant under space translations. On the other hand, it is "well-known" that associated to this space translation invariance is the momentum conservation of the equation, that is, $$
P(u,v)(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_x(t,x)v(t,x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{0,x}(x)v_0(x)dx=P(u,v)(0).
$$
Nevertheless, I have no idea how to derive this conservation law (generally speaking) just by knowing that the equation is invariant under space translations. What about time-translations for example, what is its associated conservation law? Please, don't misunderstand me, I do know how to explicitly derive the momentum conservation directly from the equation, what I would like to know is how to derive it from the space-translations invariance. Any hint suggested reading or answer is very welcome!

Comment: The equation you wrote is variational. So you can use the general formalism there to make the computation starting from an appropriate Lagrangian. (Here the action is $$-u_t^2 + u_x^2 + F(u)$$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of the scalar function $f$.) Following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Field_theory_version you can get a conserved current $j$. Integrating $j^0$ along $\{t = const\}$ gives you the time-independent conserved quantity.

Comment: Conceptually, Noether's theorem is saying that a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms of the space F of fields induces a Hamiltonian flow on T^*F, and the Hamiltonian (Noether charge) is then conserved under that flow. I wrote a blog post about this a couple of years ago: http://jde27.uk/blog/noether.html - in particular the conservation of field momentum associated with space translation is worked out. Admittedly, I find it easier to think about going from the conserved quantity to the symmetry (from Hamiltonian to its flow) but that's just because differentiating is easier than integrating.

Comment: Time-translation invariance implies the conservation of energy.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help to answer your specific question, but I hope you won't mind my taking the excuse to share Baez's exposition [Noether's theorem in a nutshell](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/noether.html), which I've always found second to none on this subject.

Comment: This theorem is known to hold for variational problems in very broad generality, but I don't think there is a theorem of this type for nonvariational problems in any generality.

Comment: @BenMcKay Every conserved current is equivalent to one s.t. its conservation condition takes the form $\mathrm{d} j[\phi] = \xi \cdot E[\phi]$ (no derivatives of the equations $E[\phi]=0$). Applying the [Helmhotz operator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Helmholtz+operator) to both sizes gives $H(\xi \cdot E[\phi])=0$, implying differential conditions on $\xi$. On appropriate equivalence classes, $j \leftrightarrow \xi$ is a bijection. When $E[\phi]=0$ is variational, the condition on $\xi$ is the same as being a symmetry of the Lagrangian.

Comment: I should have written "...applying the [Euler-Lagrange operator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Euler-Lagrange+complex) to both sides...". The Euler-Lagrange operator starts off a sequence, in the same way that the exterior derivative starts off the de Rham sequence, where the Helmholtz operator is next in the sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be blunt, the answer to your question **is** [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) (often precised as Noether's *first* theorem). So, essentially you already knew the answer to your own question.

However, the other answers are missing a degree of pragmatism. The calculation of the conserved current, once you know the Lagrangian and the symmetry is straightforward and mechanical. Namely, suppose you have a Lagrangian density $L[\phi] = L(x,\phi(x),\partial \phi(x), \partial^2\phi(x), \ldots)$, which depends your dynamical field $\phi(x)$. The variational principle will be $S(\phi) = \int L[\phi] \, \mathrm{d}x$, where $\mathrm{d}x$ is the coordinate volume form.<sup>1</sup> An infinitesimal local field transformation $\phi^a \mapsto \phi^a + \delta_{\xi}\phi^a$ is allowed to be coordinate and field dependent, $\delta_\xi \phi^a = \xi^a[\phi] = \xi^a(x,\phi(x), \partial \phi(x), \partial^2 \phi(x), \ldots)$, and commutes with coordinate derivatives, namely $\delta_\xi \partial^n \phi^a = \partial^n (\delta_\xi \phi^a) = \partial^n \xi^a[\phi]$ for any $n\ge 0$. The example of time translation $\xi^a[\phi] = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi^a$ is illustrative.

Such a local field transformation is a symmetry of the Lagrangian when its variation vanishes modulo a total divergence, $\delta_\xi L[\phi] = \partial_i J_0^i[\phi]$. The next step is a bit unintuitive, but it makes the calculation of the conserved current mechanical. Consider now the variation $\delta_{\varepsilon \xi}$, where $\varepsilon = \varepsilon(x)$ is an arbitrary function of the coordinates $x^i$. Using integration by parts, we can put the variation of the Lagrangian into the form
$$ \tag{$*$}
  \delta_{\varepsilon \xi} L[\phi]
  = \varepsilon\partial_i J^i_0[\phi] + (\partial_i\varepsilon) J^i_1[\phi] + \partial_i(-)^i .
$$
The leading term has to agree with $\delta_\xi L[\phi]$ when we set $\varepsilon \equiv 1$. The desired conserved current corresponding to $\xi$ is
$$ J_\xi^i[\phi] = J_0^i[\phi] - J_1^i[\phi] . $$
You can get the current in one step if you use integration by parts to directly put the variation of the Lagrangian into the form $\delta_{\varepsilon \xi} L[\phi] = -J_\xi^i[\phi] (\partial_i \varepsilon) + \partial_i(-)^i$, which is a formula that can be found in some physics textbooks on QFT.

The proof of Noether's theorem in this form is also straightforward (and a reshuffling of the standard proof). It only relies on the usual lemma that any density $N[\varepsilon, \ldots]$ that linearly depends on an arbitrary function $\varepsilon = \varepsilon(x)$ (and possibly any other fields) has a unique representative modulo total divergence terms, namely $N[\varepsilon, \ldots] = \varepsilon N_0 + \partial_i(-)^i$, with $N_0$ unique. The Euler-Lagrange equations $E_a[\phi]=0$ are defined by the identity $\delta_\xi = \xi^a E_a[\phi] + \partial_i(-)^i$ for arbitrary $\xi$. So, when $\xi$ is a symmetry, using $(*)$ and one more integration by parts, we find the identity
$$
  \delta_{\varepsilon \xi} L[\phi]
  = \varepsilon \xi^a E_a[\phi] + \partial_i(-)^i
  = \varepsilon \partial_i J^i_\xi[\phi] + \partial_i(-)^i ,
$$
which implies that $\partial_i J^i_\xi[\phi] = \xi^a E_a[\phi]$, which vanishes when $E_a[\phi] = 0$. In other words, $J^i_\xi[\phi]$ is a conserved current.

---

<sup>1 If you change the independent coordinates $x^i$, the Lagrangian will change by the appropriate Jacobian. Working with differential forms allows you to keep everything more manifestly invariant.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can find an overview of methods to obtain conservation laws from a wave equation in [On the structure of conservation laws of (3+1)-dimensional wave equation.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319516617302128) Noether's method requires that the PDE follows from a variational principle for a Lagrangian (as pointed out by Willie Wong). A direct algorithmic method to obtain conservation laws from a PDE without variational structure is described in the cited paper.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've thought about this stuff so take this with a grain of salt. Also, I'm only familiar with this in the context of a finite dimensional phase space, whereas the phase space is infinite-dimensional in the example you give and I'm not sure what extra subtleties that introduces. But the finite-dimensional case might still provide some useful intuition.

Those two caveats aside, I hope the following is of some use:

We can define a canonical symplectic form on phase space in terms of the Lagrangian. The symplectic form gives us a bijective correspondence between tangent vector fields and 1-forms (it works the same as with Riemannian manifolds, the key is just that we have a perfect pairing on tangent spaces). We also have a Poisson bracket operation {A, B} between scalar fields A and B. {A, B} is the Lie derivative of B along the tangent vector field corresponding to the exterior derivative of A (obtained using the correspondence between 1-forms and tangent vector fields provided by the symplectic form).

A continuous symmetry is a flow that preserves the Hamiltonian H and the symplectic form. To a continuous symmetry, we can associate a unique tangent vector field that generates it, which corresponds to a 1-form (which happens to be closed). We can then integrate that 1-form to get a scalar field, which I will call S. We have that {S, H} = 0, this basically says that the vector field corresponding to S generates a symmetry. But the Poisson bracket is anticommutative, so {H, S} = 0, implying that S is a conserved quantity (since the vector field corresponding to H generates the time-evolution flow). Therefore, continuous symmetries correspond to conserved quantities.