# Geometrical proof of Noether Theorem

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-mechanics

I am reading a very nice Physics book "The standard model in a nutshell" by D.Goldberg and just read there a mention to Noether Theorem. Of course I knew this outstanding theorem very well from previous physics courses : "A symmetry in the system (Lagrangian) implies a conserved physical quantity". The proof is quite short it follows from the Euler Lagrange equation and a few lines of calculus. But now that I think about it, I am not that happy with it. I fell like such a important result should have a more abstract and geometrical understanding. 
Do you know another proof of Noether Theorem written in a differential geometry setting and that can be generalized in a more abstract case?

Comment: You'll find a quick proof of Noether's theorem, in greater generality than you're likely to need even, in this [recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/356734).

Comment: I suppose the proof  in section 2.3.1 of this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03616.pdf  are those few line of calculus. But maybe not, you can glance it

Comment: Khavkine's answer is really excellent.

Comment: You may also be interested in the discussion here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/whats-the-interpretation-of-feynmans-picture-proof-of-noethers-theorem